# Codeigniter HMVC -> Call custom validators from MY_Form_validation.php file

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-hmvc

How to create custom form validators in `MY_Form_validation.php file` in **HMVC** and run them in any `module/controller` in **HMVC** structure for validation purpose.

note :- I have no issues in running **callback validators** working fine no issues.

I want to create some general validators which I can apply on anywhere in project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create library file like this

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    function custom() {

    }
}
```

and can call this function as you call other validation form function in HMVC

Comment: Done not working.
when i add same function to callback it works but when i add same function to `MY_Form_validation.php` its not working(removed callback_ from function name while calling).

Comment: please check syntax is proper as it may not work with same as callback.

Comment: worked thanks.
create MY_Form_validation.php file in application/libraries & copy below code for callback and custom validations  
`class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
function run($module = '', $group = '')
{
(is_object($module)) AND $this->CI =& $module;
return parent::run($group);
}
function custom($abc,$xyz)
{
  if($abc == $xyz)
            {
                $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('custom', 'this is working.');
                return false;
            }  else {
                return true;    
            }
        }`